# How to integrate a blog in an existing rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, blogs, rails-engines

I have a working rails application. I would like to add a blog to it. My requirements are:

- It should live on a subdirectory of my domain, eg: `http://www.mydomain/blog`
- It should use my application layout
- It should be optimised for Seo (pretty urls, meta tags, titles...)
- It should be relatively "full featured"

  - Markdown editor preferred (or wysiwyg editor)
  - categories and tags
  - admin section with authentication
  - comments
  - demo before I install (why nothing has a demo ?)

Do you know anything that fit those needs ?
The blog section for the website is intented to be used internally by the company. The people using it are non-technical, but they can cope with markdown or some non-intuitive feature.

I have tried:

- [comfortable-mexican-sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) Not enough features (for editing)
- [refinerycms-blog](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog). Many problems installing. Could not make it work
- [blogit](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit). Not enough features. Only the admin worked out of the box.

Comment: Any clue on this ? Wordpress seems to be a beast when we want to make it under a subdirectory. What did you choose if you have already moved on ?

Comment: I chose wordpress. I'll document here how I did it (basically creating an entry for /blog in nginx conf, and running it with php fastcgi)

Comment: A popular choice is Jekyll: http://jekyllrb.com/

Or you could set up a subdomain like blog.mydomain.com & tell your DNS to redirect to wordpress website server for that subdomain.